# Занести данные в бд при помощи цикла

Tags: sqlite, циклы

Как мне занести данные в бд при помощи цикла, например есть три поля которые мне нужно занести через цикл

```
a int=1;
b varchar;
c varchar;
while a<100
insert into table values(a,b,c)
a++;
```

Comment: Выполнить INSERT, вестимо...

В чём проблема-то? Поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: SQLite базу я не слишком хорошо знаю, и не знаю как внести данные через цикл напишите код пожалуйста

Comment: Учитывая задачу, знать какие-то особенности SQLite не нужно.

1) Открыли соединение

2) Создали команду

3) Выполнили запрос

Если требуется, то в цикле, ветвлении и во всём, что придумается.


На каком этапе проблема?

Comment: Я использую SQLite Data Browser и не знаю как там описать этот цикл

Comment: а для этого уже потребуется какой-нибудь язык программирования. SQLite Data Browser не поможет.

Comment: Используйте Python. Там встроенная поддержка SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

господа в bash

```
#!/bin/bash

SQLDB=file.sqlite
a=
b=

for i in {1..10}
do
    sqlite3 $SQLDB "insert into table values(i,b,c)"
done
```